# Exclusão de Id de Objeto

Tags: javascript

Tenho o seguinte objeto:

```
objTeste = [
  {
    "id": "03",
    "nome": "teste03",
    "pai": {
      "id": "02",
      "nome": "teste02",
      "pai": {
        "id": "01",
        "nome": "teste01"
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Estou querendo retirar todos os IDs desse objeto com JavaScript, já tentei com for mas não to conseguindo excluir o último ID. Alguém pode me ajudar?

Comment: Você poderia adicionar o código que você tem até agora?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Esse objTeste é uma array de objetos. Para remover propriedades em profundidade num objeto precisas de uma função recursiva, isto é: que se chame a sí própria a cada sub-nivel to objeto.

Criei uma que verifica se uma propriedade é um subnivel (outro objeto) e caso não seja verifica se a propriedade é `id`. Caso seja apaga-a.

```
function recursiva(obj) {
    for (var k in obj) {
        if (typeof obj[k] == "object" && obj.hasOwnProperty(k)) recursiva(obj[k]);
        else if (k == 'id') delete obj.id;
    }
}
objTeste.forEach(recursiva);
```

#### jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/93m66tx7/

Neste caso nem precisas de usar o `.map` para uma vez que mudando o objeto dentro da array ele altera diretamente  no original.

---

Se quiseres criar uma array nova, com novos objetos (sem o ID)  podes fazer assim:

```
function recursiva(obj) {
    var _obj = {};
    for (var k in obj) {
        if (typeof obj[k] == "object" && obj.hasOwnProperty(k)) _obj[k] = recursiva(obj[k]);
        else if (k != 'id') _obj[k] = obj[k];
    }
    return _obj;
}
var novo = objTeste.map(recursiva);
console.log(JSON.stringify(novo)); // [{"nome":"teste03","pai":{"nome":"teste02","pai":{"nome":"teste01"}}}]
```

#### jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/93m66tx7/1/

Comment: Obrigado é isso mesmo que eu queria.